# How to Resolve Payment Request is not defined error in GPay using Magento 2?

Tags: error, magento2.4, payment-gateway, checkout-page, googlepay

I have integrated Google Pay Extension from the marketplace.

https://marketplace.magento.com/unboundcommerce-module-googlepay.html

After integrating on my **local machine** and Configured with **Test Merchant Id**, I am getting the below error:-

[image]

could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I am facing the same issue.